# Executing shell commands through beanshell in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

Executing shell commands through beanshell in jmeter. I want to execute shell commands in beanshell preprocessor in jmeter

Can any one tell how to do so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Beanshell is JAVA (scripting language).
Below statement should help.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("COMMAND");
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on @vins answer I cloud create my ping test to verify my email server is available.

Additionally if you want to log the output of the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("COMMAND");` use something similar to this in your jmeter `BeanShell Sampler`:

```
// ********
// Ping the email server to verify it's accessible from the execution server
//
// Preconditions:
// custom variable is available named "emailServer" which contains the IP-Adress of the machine to ping
//
// ********

log.info(Thread.currentThread().getName()+": "+SampleLabel+": Ping email server: " + vars.get("emailServer"));

// Select the ping command depending on your machine type windows or Unix machine. 
//String command = "ping -n 2 " + vars.get("emailServer");    // for windows
String command = "ping -c2 " + vars.get("emailServer");    // for Unix

// Print the generated ping command
log.info(command);

// Create a process object and let this object execute the ping command
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
p.waitFor();

log.info("Execution complete.");

// Read the output of the ping command and log it
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder logCommandOutput = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while( (line = in.readLine()) != null) {
  logCommandOutput.append(line);
}
in.close();
log.info("Output: " + logCommandOutput.toString());
```

Comment: @Dev I've added comments in the answer above what the code does. If you need more specific information for a certain line, let me know.

Comment: thanks. I was trying to understand from the `Process` Object part. Why do we have to take it as a process and not just into a string. Also how does `BufferReader` work here. Do we need `StringBuilder,` can we print the output without it ?

Comment: The `Process` I took to be able to show the output in the log. I used this script in an other environment where I wanted to have the output logged. The `BufferReader` we need to actually get the output from the process and the `StringBuilder` is just convenient. I'm sure the whole thing can be reached in a simpler way.

Comment: Thanks for the details Bruno!

Comment: Adding the logging helped me!